# copy JSON files from one dir to another

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

In my web project I have the following directory  structure

```
|- target
|- foo
|- bar
|- baz
```

I'm trying to write a Grunt task that will copy all JSON files into the `target` directory from the directory whose name matches a parameter provided to the build

```
grunt.registerTask('flavor', function(srcDir) {
  var from = './' + srcDir + '/*.json';
  var dest = './target/';

  grunt.file.expand(from).forEach(function(src) {
    grunt.file.copy(src, dest);
  });   
});
```

But when I call this with

```
grunt flavor:foo
```

I get an error

> Warning: Unable to write "./target/" file (Error code: EISDIR). Use --force to continue.

Comment: I guess dest is looking for a specific filename, or using a varaible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @DanielApt mentioned, you should just use [grunt-contrib-copy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-copy). To build on his answer regarding on your comment about build-parameters, you can get them to the `task` via [grunt-option](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.option).

Way one: running different target

```
 grunt.initConfig({
    copy: {
        foo: {
            files: [
                {
                    'expand': 'true',
                    'cwd': 'foo/',
                    'src': [**],
                    'dest': 'dist/en'
                }
             ]
          },
        bar: {
            files: [/**/]
        },
        baz: {
            files: [/**/]
        }
    }
});

var target = grunt.option("target") || "foo";

grunt.registerTask("default", ["copy:" + target]);

// run with grunt --target=foo
```

Way 2: Arbituary folder with templating:

```
var target = grunt.option("target") || "foo";

grunt.initConfig({
    target: target,
    copy: {
        default_target: {
            files: [
                {
                    'expand': 'true',
                    'cwd': '<%= target %>/',
                    'src': [**],
                    'dest': 'dist/en'
                }
             ]
        },
    }
});

grunt.registerTask("default", ["copy"]);

// run with grunt --target=anyfolderhere
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to write your own task? If you don't I achieved this with [grunt-contrib-copy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-copy).

```
copy: {
            default: {
                files: [
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        src: ['foo/**', 'bar/**'],
                        dest: 'target/'
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
```

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem, because I only want to copy the files from the directory that matches the build parameter (`foo` in the example above), so the source directory needs to be set at runtime.

Comment: In that case you can replace `['foo/**']` with `[grunt.option('target') + '/**']` and call `grunt copy --target=foo`